# Converting a string to a float data type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I need to convert the contents of a Textbox (which is currency) to a datatype float.
Would I convert to single?

> txtPurchItemCorrectPrice.Text.Trim();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're dealing with currency then I would use `double` at the very least, if not `decimal`. That said you want:

```
double value = double.Parse(txtPurchItemCorrectPrice.Text.Trim());
```

If you're not sure whether it will be a number or not:

```
double value;
bool isOK = double.TryParse(txtPurchItemCorrectPrice.Text.Trim(), out value);
```

Comment: It will always be a number, since it is a currency field;

Comment: @user279521 - if you can 100% guarantee that then go with `Parse` rather than `TryParse`.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean the C# `float` type?

```
float f = float.Parse(text);
```

Or...

```
float value;
if (float.TryParse(text, out value))
{
     // Yay!
}
else
{
     // Boo! Parse failed...
}
```

Note that the code above will use the current culture. You may want to specify a different culture, e.g.

```
...
if (float.TryParse(text, out value, NumberStyles.Float,
                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
...
```

EDIT: If this is actually a float column in a database, you *may* want to use `double` instead.

Note that currency information should usually *not* be stored in using float/double; it should be stored using a *decimal* type, e.g. `decimal` (C#) and `NUMBER` (SQL).

Comment: well, this is my test in the asp side txtPurchItemCorrectPrice.Text.Trim();  and the db param is expecting a float datatype.

Comment: @user279521: So that's "float" in the database? If so, you may want "double2 on the C# side.

Comment: wish I could change the DB datatype to number... would take an act of congress. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

```
float.TryParse(…)
```

That avoids raising an exception on invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

Dim x As Double = Convert.ToDouble(txtPurchItemCorrectPrice.Text.Trim())